# how to put a comment while creating a version in aem 6.1?

Tags: aem

I want to put a comment in a particular version of a page.
It gives an option to put the comment but its not specific to a particular version.
Is there a way to put the comment while creating the version in AEM6.1?

Comment: Can you be clear with the question what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a page and have edited something in that page. Now, I am creating a version of that page, lets say version 1.0. While creating this version, I want to put some comments (Eg. Version created on 09/16). I am not able to put comment for the version of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You Can always create a comment while creating a page version from your Sidekick "Versioning" tab
[image]

Comment: Thanks! But its in the classic view. I am working in touch UI (aem 6.1). I am not able to create a comment here for the particular version.

Comment: Please raise Adobe ticket for the Adobe documentation update for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Good Observation. As per the Adobe Documentation [AEM 6.1 working with page versions](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/author/page-authoring/working-with-page-versions.html) These are the steps to be followed to created the version of the page.

**You can create a version of your resource from the timeline tab:**

1. Navigate to show the page for which you want to create a version *(In fact it is parent level).*
2. Select the page in selection mode.
3. Open the Timeline column.
4. Click/tap on the arrowhead by the comment field to list the options:
5. Select Save as Version and confirm with Create.
   The information in the timeline will be updated to indicate the new version.

[image]

And here i have noticed that the comments pushed via touch UI is not considering while Version node creation.

A little close observation at the node version properties that got created for the Classic UI vs Touch UI versions for the page. The `cq:versionComment` is missing (not created) for Touch UI process.

*The verions 1.0 and 1.2 has created with touch UI and version 1.1 created by using Classic UI*

[image: Page Version property]
[image: Classic UI Version properties]
[image]

Comment: Thats true. Thanks for the detailed explanation :). I guess I have to customize this by adding "cq:versionComment" property, if I need a comment for a particular version.

Comment: To give you an update the `/jcr:frozenNode` property `cq:versionComment` are protected.